REDUCE function can't handle a VSTACK with a blank("")
I have a vertical array with letters. I want to expand it so that every time there is a change in the letter, a blank line is inserted.

The formula in the green range works well, except that the blank line is not added.
When I add the blank line ("" in the first VSTACK, in the grey range) nothing seems to work.
The addition of the "" seems obvious to me, but fails. What am I missing?

This seems to be a bug, replacing TAKE(a;-1) with @TAKE(a;-1) or INDEX(a;ROWS(a);1) works fine though. *Credit to Elly
=REDUCE(;B3:B13;LAMBDA(a;b;IF(@TAKE(a;-1)=b;VSTACK(a;b);VSTACK(a;"";b))))



I prefer to call it bad coding rather than a bug... I noticed dynamic array is always unpredictable in LAMBDA. so I almost always use INDEX instead of TAKE or DROP in lambda. because in index, I can control the dimension of the array, and results are predictable...

but TAKE(a,-1) and @TAKE(a,-1) return the same thing, so I don't see why the first wouldn't work while the second works.

Because TAKE(a,-1) returns an 1*1 array, rather than a single value. that can sometimes cause problem in lambda.

well.. a 1x1 array is a single value.

[""] = "" won't work well in any coding language.. it will only work when you put [""] in an Excel range....

Like, you have a list of strings, with only one element, like {"a"}, then you have a string, "a", this {"a"} is just different from "a". I know this because I once check the Debugger in Excel Lab Advanced Formula Environment. TAKE(a, 1, 1) is 1*1 array, while INDEX(a, 1, 1) is a string.

I see what you mean. This makes sense.

Not sure about windows, but on my Mac, whenever I use @TAKE()....it prompts out a warning and suggest some changes..so I ended up sticking to INDEX...

@rachel The same warning appears in windows.

@VBasic2008, I see. It not only prompts warnings, it changes my formula too. that is, it adds @  in other parts the formula. that is the main reason I avoid it...

Yeah, unless you select No (right arrow).

It is called SINGLE() function ! Can read here

Add Blank Between Groups From Ungrouped Column
=LET(data,A2:A11,
    u,UNIQUE(data),
    f,FILTER(data,data=TAKE(u,1)),
    IF(ROWS(u)=1,f,REDUCE(f,DROP(u,1),LAMBDA(rr,r,
        VSTACK(rr,"",FILTER(data,data=r))))))



I recently posted a similar one for multiple columns here.


One other way using OFFSET() + EXPAND():


=DROP(REDUCE(,B2:B12,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,IF(c<>OFFSET(c,1,0),EXPAND(c,2,,""),c)))),-1)


CAVEAT: OFFSET() is a volatile function, hence will always keep recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook.

Or,
=DROP(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(B2:B12),LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,VSTACK(FILTER(B2:B12,B2:B12=c),"")))),1),-1)


Per OP's Comments:

Thank you, Mayukh However, you solution does not always seem to work.
For example, if my range starts with "a", "b", "z" ... then the "a" is
not separated from "b" by a blank, as they should, but remain together
instead.




=DROP(DROP(REDUCE(,Z1:Z4,LAMBDA(r,c,VSTACK(r,IF(c<>OFFSET(c,1,0),EXPAND(c,2,,""),c)))),1),-1)



Late to the party I see, but it's a nice question so I'll add my two cents anyways (without LAMBDA()):

Formula in B2:
=DROP(LET(x,A2:A12,IFNA(SORT(HSTACK(VSTACK(x,UNIQUE(x)),x)),"")),-1,1)

Or even:
=DROP(TOCOL(HSTACK(A2:A12,IFS(A2:A12<>A3:A13,"")),3),-1)


Thank yo, JvdV
The SORT function in your first proposal becomes a problem for me, since I do not want the letters sorted.
Your second proposal seems to work better for me.

Thanks for the feedback. Good to hear the 2nd option worked fine

Thanks to JvdV,
=LAMBDA(cur, LET(next, DROP(cur,1), TOCOL(HSTACK(cur, IF(cur<> next,"",NA())),2)))(A2:A10)


